# "Error while decoding the storage key" when backing up SQL Server database to Azure Blob using Shared Access Signature

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, database-backups

Objective: I am trying to backup our on premises SSMS databases to our Azure Cloud storage.

I have a blob container https://zutosqlbackupslive.blob.core.windows.net/dw1/
This is set to private.

I have created a Shared Access Signature with full permissions (all resource types allowed, all permissions allowed), with a start date of yesterday, and an expiry date of next year.

It is set to allo HTTPS and HTTP, using key 1.

Using this SAS, I am able to access a test image in the blob by adding it to the end of the URL for the image file. So my SAS works.

[image]

The SQL script

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [AzureDWBackup]
        WITH IDENTITY = 'Shared Access Signature',
        SECRET = '<<SAS key>>' -- this the key taken from the highlighted section of the screenshot
GO

BACKUP DATABASE Maintenance
TO URL = 'https://zutosqlbackupslive.blob.core.windows.net/dw1/Maintenance_DW1_FullBackup_20062017T1518.bak'
WITH INIT, NOFORMAT, NAME = N'Maintenance_DW1_FullBackup_20062017T1518', STATS = 10
, CREDENTIAL = N'AzureDWBackup'
```

The resulting error is:

> Msg 3298, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
>   Backup/Restore to URL device error: Error while decoding the storage key.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Can anybody see from that what is wrong, or suggest what to try next.

Comment: As [Enable SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/enable-sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure#enable-and-configure-includesssmartbackupincludesss-smartbackup-mdmd-with-default-settings) states that you need to remove the first `?` from your SAS token. Additionally, what is the version of you SQL server?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your answer.  Sorry I hadn't responded already.  I have tried following your tips, but still get the same error.  I checked that firewalls were clear, and they are.  Not sure what else would make the SAS un-decodable.

Comment: Have you created the SQL Credential as follows: `CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://{storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}] WITH IDENTITY = 'Shared Access Signature', SECRET = 'sasToken'` ?

Comment: yes.  Exactly like that.  And checked the SAS token by uploading an image to the container and accessing through the URL by appending the SAS to the end.  I have tried the SAS code in the code above with and without the leading "?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I followed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/enable-sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure) for creating a SQL Credential with the SAS URL. Here is my test, you could refer to it:

**Create a SQL Credential for the SAS URL and backup db**

```html
--Create a SQL Credential for the SAS URL
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://{storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackups] WITH IDENTITY = 'Shared Access Signature'  
,SECRET = 'st=2017-04-22T03%3A55%3A00Z&se=2017-07-29T03%3A55%3A00Z&sp=rwdl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=c&sig=Txv%2FWrStGYb6ax1dzb47WbBjO7iNCbwohl02jodhuNw%3D'

--backup the database
BACKUP DATABASE [{your-database-name}]
TO URL = 'https://{storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackups/brucedb_20160623114800.bak'
```

**Note:** You need to remove the first `?` from your SAS token.

**Result:**

[image]

[image]

Additionally, for creating a SQL Server Credential with `storage account name` and `account access key`, you could refer to [Lesson 2: Create a SQL Server Credential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720554(v=sql.120).aspx) and [Lesson 3: Write a Full Database Backup to the Windows Azure Blob Storage Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj720552(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: I think it's important to note that we need to grant at least Read, Write and Delete permissions when we create the Shared Access Signature.

Answer (score 3):

Short answers is use an Access Key instead of SAS if you are using SQL Server 2014 or earlier.

I was getting the same error using a SAS (Shared Access Signature.) My understanding was that using a SAS was the preferred method and that this would work even on older SQL Server versions.  SAS did not work on SQL Server 2014, I had to use the Access Key method and then I no longer received this error message.

I also modified the script so when I run this again, I can update the key if it ever changes.  (This makes more sense for a SAS because they expire)

```
IF EXISTS  
(SELECT * FROM sys.credentials   
WHERE [name] = '<mycredentialname>')  
BEGIN
  CREATE CREDENTIAL [<mycredentialname>] WITH IDENTITY = '<mystorageaccountname>'  
,SECRET = '<Access Key>';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
CREATE CREDENTIAL [<mycredentialname>] WITH IDENTITY = '<mystorageaccountname>'  
,SECRET = '<Access Key>';
END

BACKUP DATABASE <database name>
TO URL = 'https://<mystorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<mycontainername>/<mybackupfilename>'
WITH CREDENTIAL = '<mycredentialname>'   
     ,COMPRESSION  
     ,STATS = 1
     ,CHECKSUM ;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This - `"CREATE CREDENTIAL [AzureDWBackup]"` needs to be the access url when creating access to a shared access signature type connection.

You have used a cust0m name instead of

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://zutosqlbackupslive.blob.core.windows.net/dw1]
```

Example Template:

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>] 

   WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE' 

   , SECRET = '<shared_access_signature_key_with_removed_first_?_symbol>'
```